# Microsoft Surface Pro 3 Not Restoring

Tags: restore, microsoft-surface-pro-3

A few months ago My Surface Pro 3 automatically installed the awfully buggy first version of Windows 10 (without my permission, of course). This rendered my screen unresponsive to touch; not even my stylus works! My bluetooth keyboard trackpad and keyboard work fine but anything relating to touch is out of the question. Funnily enough the One Note button at the top of the pen stylus is the only thing that works.

I decided I would like to restore the device back to its original state as I intend to sell it. I went to:

```
Settings > Update & security > Recovery > Reset this PC > Get Started
```

and clicked `Restore Factory Settings`.

Upon doing so I received a message saying:

```
---
Could not find the recovery environment.
----------------------------------------
Insert your Windows Installation or recovery media, and 
restart your PC with the media.


---
```

I don't understand what it means. What Windows installation/recovery media? All I wish to do is a simple restoration and it is really bugging me. If somebody knows a solution to this I would be most grateful.

**Edit**: I cannot open up the Windows menu or the settings menu now; it suddenly stopped working. What do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

It means that it cannot find the recovery partition that is (often) on the OS drive that came in the machine. It may have been damaged or removed.

If it cannot be found then you need to go to Microsoft and download the Recovery Image from Microsoft's [Surface Pro Recovery Image](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-gb/support/warranty-service-and-recovery/downloadablerecoveryimage) site.

You will need a 16GB flash drive to perform the recovery.

Comment: While I recomend you use the Surface recovery image due to the unique hardware it has, you can also just download and then install Windows 8.1, and you would get the same results (except you would have to install the drivers if you actually do intend to sell it).  of course if you intend to sell it, just upgrade it to 1703, and then reset it and just sell it.  Windows 10 is 600x better then Windows 8.1